# How to interchange rows of two tables in R

Tags: r

```
a=data.frame(1:5)
b=data.frame(20:24)
```

I want to combine the two tables in an "interchangeable way", and obtain output like this:

```
    c
1   1
2  20
3   2
4  21
5   3
6  22
7   4
8  23
9   5
10 24
```

the real data are with more complex number but the idea is the same.

Comment: Do you have only one column in both the dataframes? If you have more how would your expected output look ?

Comment: Yup! only one column in both dataframes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `rbind`

```
data.frame(c = c(rbind(a$col1, b$col2)))

#    c
#1   1
#2  20
#3   2
#4  21
#5   3
#6  22
#7   4
#8  23
#9   5
#10 24
```

**data**

```
a <- data.frame(col1 = 1:5)
b <- data.frame(col2 = 20:24)
```

Comment: I got this message: data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows

Comment: that is probably because you have some different column names in your dataframe. Can you check ? I have used `col1` and `col2` as column names here.

Answer (score 0):

we can transpose and concatenate

```
data.frame(col1 = c(t(cbind(a, b))))
#   col1
#1     1
#2    20
#3     2
#4    21
#5     3
#6    22
#7     4
#8    23
#9     5
#10   24
```